# Iteration in Pointer to Pointer 2-d Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I'm doing this challenge on Hackerrank and I've tried all I could do but didn't get it right.
The challenge details are: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem

My Code is:

```
 #include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int noOfSequence, noOfQuery;
    int lastAnswer = 0, j=0;
    int query, x, y;

    cin>>noOfSequence>>noOfQuery;

    int *seqLength = new int[noOfSequence];
    for(int i=0; i<noOfSequence; i++){
        seqLength[i] = 0;
    }

    int **seqList = new int*[noOfSequence];
    for(int i=0; i<noOfSequence; i++){
        seqList[i] = new int [noOfSequence];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<noOfQuery; i++){
        cin>>query>>x>>y;
        switch(query){
            case 1: {
                        int seqListIndex = (x ^ lastAnswer) % noOfSequence;
                        *(seqList[seqListIndex] ++) = y;
                        seqLength[seqListIndex] += 1;
                        break;
                    }
            case 2: {
                        int seqListIndex = (x ^ lastAnswer) % noOfSequence;
                        lastAnswer = seqList[seqListIndex][y%seqLength[seqListIndex]];
                        cout<<lastAnswer;
                        break;
                    }
            default: cout<<"default"<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. `int **seqList` is a pointer to an array of pointers. The array of pointers are further pointing towards the individual arrays of `int`.

2.`int *seqLength` is a pointer to array of intergers. This array of integers is keeping track of the length of arrays mentioned above.
3.`int seqListIndex` denotes the index of the array of pointers.

I guess there's something wrong with the way the `lastAnswer` is computed.I've checked it in every possible way i can but still couldn't find anything.
I've also tried to understand how we iterate over the int array but a little more knowledge would be great.

Comment: *but didn't get it right*. What do you mean by right?

Comment: Why don't you use vectors? And you do know that `^` is the bitwise [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator?

Comment: Um.... the auto-generator included `<vector>` for a not-so-subtle hint as to what you should be using to solve this in C++.

Comment: Furthermore, and this might be the source of your problem, when you do `seqList[seqListIndex] ++` you lose the original pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're treating `seqList[seqListIndex]` as a pointer to the "next element", but `y%seqLength[seqListIndex]` is an offset from its original value.

The index of the "next element" is `seqLength[seqListIndex]`, so replace

```
*(seqList[seqListIndex] ++) = y;
```

with

```
seqList[seqListIndex][seqLength[seqListIndex]] = y;
```

(Your code could be much simplified if you used `std::vector`.)

Comment: thank you for the solution. I understood why it worked. But didn't understand the "offset" thing.